# Setting Managed metadata field

Tags: powershell, splistitemcollection

I am trying to update a managed metadata field  but I get an error saying `Property 'ListItemCollectionPosition' cannot be found on this object'$spQuery.<<

```
$site1 = Get-SPSite mysite

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy")
$site2 = $site1
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site2)
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["mygroup"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets[mytermset"]
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(100)
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq "Off"}

$web1 = Get-SPWeb myweb
$list1 = "Board meetings"
$list2 = $web1.Lists[$list1]


if($list2.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
{ 

 $Count = $List.Folders.Count + $list.Items.Count    
 if($list2.Fields.ContainsField("marking") -eq $true)
 {
   $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
   $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
   $query.RowLimit = 2000
   $caml = '<Where><AND><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" /><Value Type="Text">Off-S</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" /><Value Type="Text">Off-S</Value></Neq></AND></Where>' +

   $query.Query = $caml

  do
  {
   $listItems = $list2.GetItems($query)
   $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
   foreach($item in $listItems)
   {
    #Cast to SPListItem to avoid ambiguous overload error
    $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;
    #Get the taxonomy field for the list item
    $taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["GPMS marking"]

    $taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem,$term)
    $spItem.SystemUpdate()
   }
  }
   while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a an `SPQuery` object with name `$query`

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
```

But then you are using `$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition`. Change it to `$query.ListItemCollectionPosition` Also change `while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)` to `while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)`